# The application crashes because it may be doing too much work on its main Thread

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-listview, android-asynctask

Maybe this is answered before but i couldnt find any identical solution to this but proposals. I am building an app in which i populate 4 `ListViews` from `Mysql` database through JSON. The work is being done at 4 fragments. The thing is that when i populate the 2 Lists from database and the other 2 just with some string array data everything works fine but when i try to populate all 4 of them at the same time then it crashes.

The Error:

```
01-04 11:27:25.405    3002-3017/com.order.app.order W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-04 11:27:25.405    3002-3017/com.order.app.order W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa31ff7a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-04 11:27:30.619    3002-3002/com.order.app.order I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 307 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

My Fragment:

```
private View rootView;
    private ListView lv;
    private ArrayAdapter<ProductList> adapter;
    private String jsonResult;
    private String url = "http://reservations.cretantaxiservices.gr/files/getkafedes.php";
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    List<ProductList> customList;
    private TextView tv1, tv2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_coffees_fragment, container, false);
        lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.coffeesListView);
        final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().getApplicationContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean network_connected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isAvailable() && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (!network_connected) {
            onDetectNetworkState().show();
        } else {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                accessWebService();
                registerCallClickBack();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        accessWebService();
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    private AlertDialog onDetectNetworkState() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        builder1.setMessage(R.string.wifi_off_message)
                .setTitle(R.string.wifi_off_title)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                getActivity().finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.action_settings,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                startActivityForResult((new Intent(
                                        Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)), 1);
                                getActivity().finish();
                            }
                        });
        return builder1.create();
    }



    private void registerCallClickBack() {
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "You have chosen " + customList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.show();
            } else {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (onDetectNetworkState().isShowing()
                    && onDetectNetworkState() != null) {
                onDetectNetworkState().show();
            } else {
                onDetectNetworkState().dismiss();
            }
        }
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.show();
            } else {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (onDetectNetworkState().isShowing()) {
                onDetectNetworkState().show();
            } else {
                onDetectNetworkState().dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
    public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public JsonReadTask() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setTitle(R.string.waiting);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.get_stocks));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ListDrawer();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        task.execute(new String[]{url});
    }

    public void ListDrawer() {
        customList = new ArrayList<ProductList>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("kafedes");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
                String image = jsonChildNode.optString("image");
                customList.add(new ProductList(image, name, price));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }

        adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, customList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

As a matter of fact i am using 4 `AsyncTasks` to do this job. Any ideas???

**EDIT:**

I updated the code since i found something online but still the same error

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(customList == null){
            accessWebService();
        }else{
            ListDrawer();
        }
    }
```

Any Help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Could i use 1 AsyncTask to populate the 4 Listviews?? How am i going to separate the data??

Comment: The "application may be doing too much work.." message doesn't itself lead to crash, if your application is crashing then explore the stack trace to find the exception.

Comment: "Skipped 307 frames" this is not a crash!

Comment: The fact is that actually it gives me only this message. It just takes me back to the Mainactivity. it does not give me any errors. I read somewhere that 300+ frames is actually too much work. So any ideas to reduce it??

Comment: Can i do the work in the activity where i setup the ViewPager??If yes how am i going to separate the data to populate each listview??

Comment: Where is the error message that causes your application to crash????

Comment: Catch blocks should always have a `e.printStackTrace();` !

Comment: it just tell me that 307 frames skipped and then it goes to my 1st screen. is there any way to call asynctasks as i swipe tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in this method you are actully in the UI thread

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ListDrawer();
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

And you calling the `ListDrawer();` method and it's going to do a CPU intensive task, parsing the JSON.
It throws an exception in that method and calls this `getActivity().finish();` in the catch block. That's why you getting back to your previous activity.
Try parsing your JSON in the `AsynckTask` and it solves your problem for sure.

Update:

```
private View rootView;
private ListView lv;
private ArrayAdapter<ProductList> adapter;
private String jsonResult;
private String url = "http://reservations.cretantaxiservices.gr/files/getkafedes.php";
ProgressDialog pDialog;
List<ProductList> customList;
private TextView tv1, tv2;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_coffees_fragment, container, false);
    lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.coffeesListView);
    final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().getApplicationContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean network_connected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isAvailable() && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    if (!network_connected) {
        onDetectNetworkState().show();
    } else {
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            accessWebService();
            registerCallClickBack();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    accessWebService();
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return rootView;
}

private AlertDialog onDetectNetworkState() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    builder1.setMessage(R.string.wifi_off_message)
            .setTitle(R.string.wifi_off_title)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            getActivity().finish();
                        }
                    })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.action_settings,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            startActivityForResult((new Intent(
                                    Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)), 1);
                            getActivity().finish();
                        }
                    });
    return builder1.create();
}



private void registerCallClickBack() {
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "You have chosen " + customList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.show();
        } else {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (onDetectNetworkState().isShowing()
                && onDetectNetworkState() != null) {
            onDetectNetworkState().show();
        } else {
            onDetectNetworkState().dismiss();
        }
    }
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.show();
        } else {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (onDetectNetworkState().isShowing()) {
            onDetectNetworkState().show();
        } else {
            onDetectNetworkState().dismiss();
        }
    }
}
public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, List<ProductList>> {
    public JsonReadTask() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setTitle(R.string.waiting);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.get_stocks));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ProductList> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            customList = new ArrayList<ProductList>();

            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("kafedes");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
                String image = jsonChildNode.optString("image");
                customList.add(new ProductList(image, name, price));

            }
            return customList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ProductList> customList) {
        if(customList == null){
            Log.d("ERORR", "No result to show.");
            return;
        }
        ListDrawer(customList);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}// end async task

public void accessWebService() {
    JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{url});
}

public void ListDrawer(List<ProductList> customList) {

    adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, customList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: so you are telling me to modify the onPostExecute and instead of ListDrawer() method to call the accesswebservice() method where i execute the task??can you please give me an example with code???

Comment: i will try this and let you know

Comment: I corrected my answer in some lines, make sure you use the last edition

Comment: with your solution it gives me this error

android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.order.app.order.NewOrder has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3749b548 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1026,483} that was originally added here

on preExecute in pDialog.show();

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the field:

```java
private String jsonResult;
```

from both background thread (in **doInBackground** methods of your AsyncTasks) and from UI thread in **ListDrawer()** method in the line:

```java
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
```

The most likely cause of your crash is that the UI thread doesn't see that the jsonResult value was set (since the field isn't volatile) and creating of new JSONObject throws an exception.

The solution would be to perform the parsing of the response in the **doInBackground()** method of your async task and return ArrayList from it (**EDIT**: fixed compile errors)

```java
@Override
protected ArrayList<ProductList> doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        ArrayList<ProductList> customList = new ArrayList<ProductList>();

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("kafedes");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
            String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
            String image = jsonChildNode.optString("image");
            customList.add(new ProductList(image, name, price));
        }

        return customList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**onPostExecute()** method should be modified:

```java
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ProductList> result) {
    pDialog.dismiss();

    if(result == null) {
        getActivity().finish();
    } else {
        adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, customList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

finally the signature of your AsyncTask has to be changed:

```java
public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<ProductList>, Void, String> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: in your solution it gives me multiple errors about doInBackground method